# Generate and deploy certificate using: Letsencrypt + Docker + AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, kubernetes, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt

I'm trying to generate a certificate in my local (MacBook) environment which I can package in my Docker image and deploy into my AWS environment via Kubernetes.

I've scoured sources online for a solution to this but I'm unable to find the details I need.

From my macbook:

```
sudo certbot certonly -a standalone -d my.domain
```

Gives me this error:

```
Failed authorization procedure. my.domain (http-01): urn:acme:error:unauthorized :: 
The client lacks sufficient authorization :: Invalid response from 
http://my.domain/.well-known/acme-challenge/T8jtGQswRuMgHKIhGvb-
QD73kytTZnHfH5mK5lEZUJc: "{"timestamp":"2018-04-22T22:33:40.845+0000","status":404,
"error":"Not Found","message":"No message available","path":"/.well-kno"
```

Clearly, I need a way to prove that I own my own domain. How can I do this locally?

Comment: so why not use the aws free service "certificate manager" to do this easy job?

Comment: Maybe they'd like to manage their own certificates, or work reasons, or maybe it's a lab, or just fiddling around

Comment: @BMW I got lost in a rabbit hole trying to deploy a Kubernetes LoadBalancer service using Amazon's ACM for two days, only to come out the other side and realise you can't redirect HTTP traffic to HTTPS using the ARN. Hopeless. Now I'm back where I started and will try to do it with Letsencrypt again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to verify ownership of the domain from your macbook you have these two options as stated in the certbot docs:

- Use a DNS plugin - https://certbot.eff.org/docs/using.html#dns-plugins
- Use the manual method - https://certbot.eff.org/docs/using.html#manual

While the standalone option does not require web server software it does require that it is run on the target web server - it is therefore not what you need to do and will result in the failure reported in your question.